# Recommended commentary on the Mesilas Yeshorim of the Ramchal?

Tags: product-recommendation, commentaries, mesilas-yesharim

Are there any well-accepted commentators on the Mesilas Yeshorim of the Ramchal?

The [Lehmann's website](https://www.lehmanns.co.uk/catalogsearch/result/?q=%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA+%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D)  has amongst others:

מסילת ישרים עם פירוש יודע לשאול

מסילת ישרים עם פירוש מסילות יהודה

מסילת ישרים - בתוספת ראשי פרקים וביאורים

מסילת ישרים עם פירוש ובו תדבק

Which commentary do you recommend?

Comment: Most people learn it without commentary. I don't think any commentary is popular. For more in depth explanation, see Rav Salomon's Matnas Chelko: https://www.eichlers.com/matnas-chelko-al-mesilas-yesharim-solomon.html